# Can't import a Stimulus component to my Rails application: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

Tried to follow te set up guide for this NestedForm Stimulus component: [Installation](https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-rails-nested-form/)

Like so:

```bash
$ npm install stimulus-rails-nested-form --save
```

app/javascript/controllers/application.js

```js
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import NestedForm from 'stimulus-rails-nested-form' // Added this

const application = Application.start()
application.register('nested-form', NestedForm) // Added this

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

And I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "stimulus-rails-nested-form". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I can see the package properly installed in the node_modules directory and Stimulus is getting loaded properly as I'm using it in other places of the application.

[image]

I'm on Rails 7.0.4.

Appreciate any help, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you share a bit more about your rails setup that might help.

Your Rails app might not know about your javascripts... have a look here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

You will either need to use importmaps (in which scenario you wouldn't need npm), or you use esbuild or webpack (I would not recommend the latter).

Comment: Actually adding the component via rails importmaps fixed it without having to change anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should use import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus' in your javascript controller
**example:**
*hello_controller.js*

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    console.log("you are good boy")
  }
}
```